# Xcode debug memory gauge in code

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, memory

How to get something like Xcodes debug memory gague value from code? Resident size is nowhere close to that value.

[image: Xcode memory gauge]

Edit: It has to work on non-simulated iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look in `DTrace`(dynamic tracing framework) scripts.

Also, there are some projects that help you to trace the memory allocations.
https://github.com/facebook/FBMemoryProfiler

Comment: Unfortunately DTrace does not work on iOS (simulated only). FBMemoryProfiler values are far from Xcode memory gauge values since they only track allocations.